# Changing the slider into buttonMode

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to change the slider into `buttonMode` by using

```
my_slider.buttonMode = true;
```

but it doesn't shows `handsymbol`.Is there any other way to change the slider into buttonMode?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the similar issue in one of my project. try this it will definitely work.

```
// cmp_slider is component instance

var mc = cmp_slider.getChildAt(1); // it is a drag button.
mc.buttonMode = true;
mc.useHandCursor = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_slider.mouseChildren = false;
my_slider.buttonMode = true;
```

Comment: use `getChildByName("mcName")`. Can u post your `drag` function?

Comment: Here is the correct code to make the slider into buttonMode
a_mc is the instance name of my component

a_mc.buttonMode = true;
BaseButton(a_mc.getChildAt(1)).useHandCursor=true;
BaseButton(a_mc.getChildAt(0)).useHandCursor=true;


its working perfectly.

Comment: BaseButton(a_mc.getChildAt(1)).buttonMode=true;

Comment: No,to change the slider childrens into buttonMode we can use only

BaseButton(a_mc.getChildAt(1)).useHandCursor=true;

Comment: s.then y u have used `useHandCursor=true`.?

Answer (score 0):

`my_slider.mouseChildren=false` is sufficient to display a hand cursor over a component.

EDIT:

`my_slider.useHandCursor=true` is also required

Comment: Its not working.

Here is the correct code to make the slider into buttonMode
a_mc is the instance name of my component

a_mc.buttonMode = true;

BaseButton(a_mc.getChildAt(1)).useHandCursor=true;
BaseButton(a_mc.getChildAt(0)).useHandCursor=true;


its working perfectly.