# How do I use BaseButton?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I read a [response to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291765/changing-the-slider-into-buttonmode) that involves using BaseButton in the solution.

I tried using BaseButton but Flex does not recognize it as a class. I looked at the API for BaseButton, but I am still unable to use it. 
How do I implement this code:

```
var hSlider:HSlider = new HSlider;
hSlider.buttonMode = true; 
BaseButton(hSlider.getChildAt(1)).useHandCursor=true
BaseButton(hSlider.getChildAt(0)).useHandCursor=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `BaseButton` class in Flex environment. Full name of this class if `fl.controls.BaseButton` and `fl.*` is fla-based class which you can't use while build in FlexBuilder (In general this is true, although there are workarounds).
To use it inside of FlexBuilder you should export all `fl.controls.*` classed you need (including `HSlider`) as swc library.

Furthermore, I bet you slider is `mx.controls.HSlider` or even `spark.components.HSlider` which both have another than `fl.controls.HSlider` class structure and do not include BaseButton objects so for you current code structure you cann't use it in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that case, how would I go about getting the hand cursor to work on an HSlider, or should I add this as a separate question?

Comment: I think you could use this question. Just clarify what HSlider do you use and what result you want achive.